# flutter firebase multi factor authentication or MFA doesnt work . FirebaseAuthMultiFactorException doesnt work or get called

Tags: flutter, firebase, multi-factor-authentication

### I'm using flutter Firebase multi factor authentication mfa but

```
FirebaseAuthMultiFactorException catch (e) {
      final firstHint = e.resolver.hints.first;
      if (firstHint is! PhoneMultiFactorInfo) {
        return;
      }
```

doesn't get called at all, i added break point but nothing , its like this is getting completely ignored and only the signInWithEmailAndPassword gets called. the full code is :

```
final auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

  void mfa(String loginEmail, loginPassword) async {
    try {
      await auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
        email: loginEmail,
        password: loginPassword,
      );
    } on FirebaseAuthMultiFactorException catch (e) {
      final firstHint = e.resolver.hints.first;
      if (firstHint is! PhoneMultiFactorInfo) {
        return;
      }
      await FirebaseAuth.instance.verifyPhoneNumber(
        multiFactorSession: e.resolver.session,
        multiFactorInfo: firstHint,
        verificationCompleted: (_) {},
        verificationFailed: (_) {},
        codeSent: (String verificationId, int? resendToken) async {
          final smsCode = await getSmsCodeFromUser(context);

          if (smsCode != null) {
            final credential = PhoneAuthProvider.credential(
              verificationId: verificationId,
              smsCode: smsCode,
            );

            try {
              await e.resolver.resolveSignIn(
                PhoneMultiFactorGenerator.getAssertion(
                  credential,
                ),
              );
            } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
              print(e.message);
            }
          }
        },
        codeAutoRetrievalTimeout: (_) {},
      );
    } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
      if (e.code == 'user-disabled') {
        print("firebase auth exception $e");
      } else {
        print("firebase auth exception $e");
        return null;
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print("generic error: $e");
      return null;
    }
  }
}
```

i tried using cubits and literally made a new project because i thought it had issues . i updated all my pub dependencies but nothing is working